# Why I can 't delete the empty row?

Tags: perl

The file A contains one row like below,

```
SNP1 AA TT GGSNP2 GG CC AASNP3 GG CC AA...
```

I want to change the format and make it like this,

```
SNP1    TT      AA      TT      GG      CC      AA
SNP2    AA      GG      CC      TT      GG      CC
SNP3    GG      AA      TT      TT      CC      TT
```

...
(each row began with SNP_)
I had written a perl script to replace SNP by \nSNP, but the first row of the output file was always empty though I had done some try to delete the first row.
So, Is there any suggestion for me? Or another way to get the final output file. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, then it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: Why did you want `AA TT GG` to become `TT AA TT GG CC AA`? Is there a formula that you use? Please explain

Comment: All you need to do is omit the very first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure there is a character before every `SNP` that you alter:

```
s/.\K(?=SNP)/\n/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open $file_in...
open $file_out...
local $/ = 'SNP';
<$file_in>; # discard empty row
while ( my $record = <$file_in> ) {
    chomp $record;
    # make changes to $record, which will start as e.g. "1 AA TT GG"
    ....
    print $file_out "SNP$record\n";
}
```